# Creating two columns from an unstructured file of IDs and sequences

Tags: python-3.x

Problem: Working with python 3.x, I have a file called input.txt with content as below

```
2345673    # First ID
0100121102020211111002  # first sequence (seq) which is long and goes to several lines
0120102100211001101200
6758442   #Second ID
0202111100011111022222  #second sequence (seq) which is long and goes to several lines
0202111110001120211210
0102101011211001101200
```

What i want: To process input.txt and save the results in output.csv and when i read it in pandas the 
result should be a data frame like below.

```
ID            Seq
2345673       0   1  0  0  1  2  1  1  0   2    …
6758442       0   2  0  2  1  1  1  1  0   0    …
```

Below is my code

```
 with open("input.txt") as f:
    with open("out.csv", "w") as f1:
        for i, line in enumerate(f): #read each line in file
            if(len(line) < 15 ): #check if length line is say < 15
                id = line # if yes, make line ID
            else:
                seq = line # if not make it a sequence
                #print(id)
                lines = []
                lines.append(','.join([str(id),str(seq)]))
                for l in lines:
                    f1.write('('+l+'),\n') #write to file f1
```

when i read out.csv in pandas the output is not what i want. see below. Please i will appreciate your help , i am really stocked.

```
(2345673  
,0100121102020211111002  
),
(2345673  
,0120102100211001101200
),
(6758442   
,0202111100011111022222  
),
(6758442   
,0202111110001120211210
),
(6758442   
,0102101011211001101200),
```

Comment: Seems nobody is giving a suggestion on how to go around this.Hopefully someone says something . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
### idea is to create two lists: one with ids and another with sequences
with open("input.txt") as f:         
    ids=[]
    seqs=[]
    seq=""
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if (len(line) < 15 ) :
            seqs.append(seq)
            id=line
            id=id.rstrip('\n')
            id=id.rstrip('  ')
            ids.append(id)
            seq=""
        else:
            #next three lines combine all sequences that correspond the same id into one 
            additional_seq = line.rstrip('\n')
            additional_seq = additional_seq.rstrip('  ')
            seq+=additional_seq
    seqs.append(seq)
    seqs=seqs[1:]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ids, seqs)), columns =['id', 'seq']) 
df.to_scv("out.csv",index=False)
```